# Mac does not finish rebooting, can't remote connect

Tags: ssh, remote-control, reboot

I have a Mac Mini, M1, which I use remotely via SSH / VNC.

From time to time I need to issues a reboot to the machine.

After rebooting however, I am unable to establish an SSH connection as all I get are 'Connection Refused' packets.

It seems that machine does not actually finish the boot process until first login; only after entering my password on the local machine does it start accepting SSH connections.

How can I make the Mac actually finish booting without someone physically at the machine?

Comment: Have you turned on FileVault?

Comment: Ahhh, yes I do - this is probably the reason then? It's awaiting the decryption phrase?

Comment: Yep. I think the process is slightly different on M1 Macs, but basically it can't unlock the encrypted disk to load the OS until it gets a valid password.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on physical security requirements at the far end, you could set it to auto-login

[image]

Comment: This is an option... as when I have the VNC session the remote desktop is active - but this would allow anyone to walk up to the machine, reboot it, and have access to the desktop without me being aware. I'd prefer the machine to just finish the boot process.